# <img src(unknown)>

Tags: php

Есть такая конструкция

```
<a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="<?php echo $LOGGED_IN = user_isloggedin() ? $user['photo'] : "images/avatars/question-mark.png"; ?>"></a>
```

ожидается, что когда пользователь авторизован, мы видим его фото, если не авторизован, то мы видим заглушку. В первом случае все прекрасно работает, во втором случае получаем `<img src(unknown)>`. В конструкции ошибки, хоть убейте, я не вижу. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Возможно, проверка выполнения user_isloggedin() всегда заканчивается на $user['photo'], просто когда пользователь авторизован, есть путь к его фото, а когда не авторизован, нету.

Answer (score 0):

С синтаксисом ошибок нет. Какая ошибка? 
Может в *$user* нет ключа или это вообще не массив. 
Может *user_isloggedin* не доступна.
А может просто в пути ошибка. не хватает слеша или т.п. Смотрите какой урл у вас формируется

Comment: по идее, src(unknown) - это отсутствие или пустой атрибут src. Так что, дело не в пути

Comment: *В первом случае все прекрасно работает,*  - с юзером, значит, все хорошо

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под " В конструкции ошибки" ?
Просто не выводится картинка или вы видите какую-то ошибку (варнинг, нотис, фатал) ?

Comment: Да, с юзером все хорошо. Не срабатывает else . И тут мне непонятно... В первом случае все работает, значит $LOGGED_IN == true; Логично предположить, что во втором случае $LOGGED_IN == false , но почему же в таком случае не срабатывает else ?

Comment: Не то, чтобы "не выводится картинка", путь в атрибут src не выводится вообще!

Comment: Пустая строка? что содержит $user['photo'] ?
Как писал уже выше, синтаксис правильный. Продебажте каждый элемент (выведете его var_dump-ом на крайняк)

Comment: $user['photo'] содержит путь к аватару авторизованного пользователя. Если пользователь авторизован, то все срабатывает. Кроме пути к аватару $user содержит также номер телефона пользователя и его адрес, и все без проблем выводится когда пользователь авторизован.

Comment: if ($LOGGED_IN = user_isloggedin()) {
                $photo_path = $user['photo'];
            } else {
                $photo_path = "images/avatars/question-mark.png";
            }
            ?>

            <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="<?php echo $photo_path; ?>"></a>

Comment: Сделал уже так, результат один <img src(unknown)>

Comment: По совету Виталия, опытным путем установлено, что $photo_path; выводится вне условия. Таким образом, не срабатывает else -условие . Я вообще сбит с толку. Если не срабатывает else , должно срабатывать if - условие . Но если пользователь не авторизован и оно не срабатывает. Бывает такое, что в if - else конструкции не срабатывают оба условия??

Comment: Видимо, срабатывает всегда $LOGGED_IN == true, но если пользователь не авторизован, то $user ничего не содержит. Это запутывает меня еще больше, потому как $user = get_data() выполняется в аналогичной if- конструкции if($LOGGED_IN = user_isloggedin()

Comment: Пардон, вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#user">
<img class="circle" src="<?php $LOGGED_IN = user_isloggedin() ? echo $user['photo'] : echo "images/avatars/question-mark.png"; ?>">
</a>
```

Попробуйте так должно получится